# Very basic ask about databases/SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have a school project to do where I have to make a webpage where you have a box where you type in your postcode/zip number and it searches a database and shows you information about your area.

I already have all the data all clean on an Excel sheet... Just have literally no idea what to do next...

What language/how do I store data in a coding language etc. etc.

Someone please help!

Comment: What level of class is this?

Comment: Do you have access to a Database? If so which one? If not you can build a DataTable from your Excel sheet, using OleDbConnection

Comment: It's very basic level!! I don't have access to a database but am considering all options so could look into it. What would you recommend?

Comment: By the way thank you so much for replying this is extremely kind of you

Answer (score 0):

Well for SQL Database you have a few options, MySQL, SQLite and Postgres. All of these are very similar.

1. First you could start by thinking of which programming language you are most comfortable with.
2. Looking at your data and design database schema
3. Next look into the how to connect to your chosen database with your language.
4. try writing query to retrieve data from db and print the result out

Comment: OK cool thank you! 

Do you know of a good text writer for SQL? And do you know how I would integrate SQL with my webpage/HTML? As you can tell I am very clueless

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply

Comment: you would need some sort of web service in the middle, that will talk to the database and send the information back to html for rendering. The web service and controller is written in python. Here is an example of webpage interact with SQL DB https://github.com/MUIC-CS/summer2017-week2-tabkeeper/